# org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': BeanPostProcessor - nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, gradlew

Tomcat is throwing below Error while deploying the Spring application

```
2022-10-04 09:23:34.427 INFO  [factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2022-10-04 09:23:34.584 WARN  [context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
2022-10-04 09:23:34.586 ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5720)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
    ... 19 more
```

Gradle dependency tree looks like

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.7.3
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.7.3
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.7.3
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-`aop`:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.23
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.23
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.22 -> 5.3.23 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:5.3.23
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.23
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.23
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.23 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.23
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.0 -> 2.13.2 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.0 -> 2.13.2.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1
+--- com.javadocmd:simplelatlng:1.0.1
+--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0
|    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
+--- org.drools:drools-compiler:5.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.drools:drools-core:5.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.mvel:mvel2:2.1.0.drools4
|    |    \--- org.drools:knowledge-api:5.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.3
|    |    \--- org.antlr:stringtemplate:3.2.1
|    |         \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    +--- org.antlr:antlr:3.3
|    |    \--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.3 (*)
|    +--- org.antlr:stringtemplate:3.2.1 (*)
|    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    +--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.5.1
|    \--- org.mvel:mvel2:2.1.0.drools4
+--- com.trilead:trilead-ssh2:1.0.0-build222
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
+--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (c)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.23 (c)
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (c)
\--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.23 (c)
```

I have transitive dependency from other jar for
compileOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.2'
compileOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.0'

I have removed all the transitive occurrence of aop dependencies, but Still facing the same issue.
I have Looked in to the class method implementation is there. somehow it is not recognizing it or may be pointing to some other version.

Comment: Could you provide the `build.gradle` which can reproduce the error?

Comment: Those error come from mixing jars of different versions of a framework or using incompatible versions. As you haven't provided the full stracktrace it is unclear which class/method it concerns. However you are mixing AspectJ 1.8 and 1.9 which is a bad idea to do, fix those versions to match and it needs to be 1.9 for Spring 5.3 to support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me correct direct.

Found My issue, Reason was I have activemq-all dependency in my project, which has an older version of spring, shipped with it. This spring dependency is not showing in dependency tree because it is contained in same activemq-all jar.